# Не получается проверить треугольник

Tags: c

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
    float a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    printf("Введите стороны треугольника: \n");
    printf("a=");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\nb=");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("\nc=");
    scanf("%f", &c);

    if (a*b == b*b+c*c){
        printf("Треугольник прямоугольный.");
    }

    else if (b*b == a*a+c*c){
        printf("Треугольник прямоугольный.");
    }

    else if (c*c == a*a+b*b){
        printf("Треугольник прямоугольный.");
    }

    else{
        printf("Треугольник не прямоугольный.");
    }
        
    
}
```

Задача: Проверить является ли треугольник прямоугольным. Пробовал египетский - не работает.

Comment: 1) `scanf("%d", &a);` -> `scanf("%f", &a);`. 2) `a*b` -> `a*a` 3) Не проверять числа с плавающей точкой на строгое равенство в силу [особенностей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453) арифметики с плавающей точкой.

Comment: А вы бы еще более странное условие написали — `a*b == b*b+c*c`