# Есть код написаный на Си, и мне нужно чтобы цикл сработал 10 раз

Tags: c

Ниже есть код, в котором выводится значение р= -6.08999999999999985789, а мне надо чтобы выводило -6.09, и да я знаю что оно выведет то что мне надо если заменю 20 на просто 2, но в ячейке память будет держать то длинное число и из-за этого цикл не срабатывает 10 раз Как это сделать?

```
#include
#include
#include
#define a 8.3
#define b 1.43
#define xfinish -4.74
#define deltx 0.15
#define N 10

int main()
{
double p, d, xstart, step;

xstart=-1*((N-1)*deltx-(xfinish));
printf("%.2f", xstart);

for( p = xstart; p <= xfinish; p += deltx ) {
printf("Значение аргумента p= %.20lf\n", p);
d=pow(2, -p)*(sqrt(labs(p+pow(labs((p-a)), 1/4.))*(exp(b))));
printf("Значение d=%.2f\n", d);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453).

Answer (score 1):

6.09 не представимо в виде `double` точно в силу ограничений чисел с плавающей точкой. Если вам надо ровно 10 выполнений — лучше всего стройте цикл на основе целых чисел.

```
int main()
{
    double p, d, xstart, step;

    xstart=-1*((N-1)*deltx-(xfinish));
    printf("%.2f\n", xstart);

    p = xstart;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        printf("Значение аргумента p= %.20lf\n", p);
        d=pow(2, -p)*(sqrt(labs(p+pow(labs((p-a)), 1/4.))*(exp(b))));
        printf("Значение d=%.2f\n", d);
        p += deltx;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

См. https://ideone.com/dQHFPe