# Как остановить выполнение метода в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

По этому скрипту объект Background должен менять свою форму (что он и делает) но в методе Enter есть вычисление, которое находит разницу между настоящим размером и нужным и заканчивается только при условии, что разница равна нулю, что никогда не произойдёт из-за вычисления. Теперь мне нужно либо принудительно остановить метод, или каким-то образом осуществить условие завершения.
Проблема в том, что переменная i (настоящий размер по оси x) никогда не равна 2 (нужный размер) и зацикливается на 1.999999... (А Change вообще выходит на 1.оченьМногоЦифриБукв) Можно что нибудь с этим сделать?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Button : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    [Header("Set manualy")]
    [Tooltip("This is the backline, that will be activaited when the mouse is on button")]
    public GameObject Background;
    [Tooltip("Set how long the line will become, when mouse is on it")]
    public float      Selected;
    public float      Speed;
    [Header("Sets automatically")]
    public RectTransform rt;
    public float      Change;
    public float      i;


    void Awake() {
        rt = Background.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        i = 1;
    }


    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData) {
        Invoke("Enter", 0f);
    }

    void Enter() {
        print("Still using Enter");
        Change = Selected - i;

        i += Change * Speed;
        rt.anchorMax = new Vector2(i, 1);
        if (Change == 0) { Invoke("Enter", 0f);}
    }


    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData) {
        Invoke("Exit", 0f);
    }

    void Exit() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема с `float` такая, что у них есть некоторые особенности. Читайте про них тут: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/191482)

Поэтому как вариант: нужно сравнивать `Change` не с точным значением 0, а с некой дельтой, которая вас устраивала бы. Т.е. например `if (Change < 0.1)`

Comment: Да поменял на `i < 1.9` и заработало