# Как умножить 2 float числа не используя знак умножения?

Tags: javascript

Как умножить 2 float числа не используя знак умножения?

Числа могут быть любые.

```
let a = 0.1;
let b = 0.2;
```

Comment: math.multiply(a, b)

Comment: Почему до сих пор никто не задал вопрос — нафига?

Comment: Почему никто не задал вопрос - а как в школе столбиком перемножали с использованием таблицы умножения? Компьютер по волшебству умножение производит? Составьте таблицу умножения, держите в уме десятки, складывайте. А так вы только синтаксис меняете. Вместо таблицы можно складывать соответствующую цифру необходимое количество раз))

Comment: @AlexeyTen, судя по комментариям, автор вопроса просто хочет получить в результате умножения ровно `0.02`, а не `0.020000000000000004...`

Comment: Если надо получить "точные" результаты при операциях с числами, то не используйте `float`. Целые числа позволяют хранить количество молекул на Земле. Переводите метры в миллиметры или нанометры, все расчеты производите в этих единицах, а при выводе преобразовывайте как надо. Это вам не математика, это реальный мир.

Comment: @wololo как там Ксанф говорил, как только автор предоставит точные числа 0.1 и 0.2 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Способов несколько

1. использование деления

   ```
    const res = a / (1 / b);
   ```

Способ универсальный по сравнению со способом 2), НЕДОСТАТОК - если `b = 0`, то способ не работает

2. используя логарифмы и экспоненту

   ```
    const res = Math.exp(Math.log(a) + Math.log(b))
   ```

2.1) аналогично 2, но можно использовать степень и логарифм по основанию 10:

```
    const res = Math.pow(10, Math.log10(a) + Math.log10(b))
```

2.2) аналогично 2, но можно использовать степень и логарифм по основанию 2:

```
    const res = Math.pow(2, Math.log2(a) + Math.log2(b))
```

вообще тут можно много вариантов с логарифмами привести, ведь можно использовать и логарифм с произвольным основанием

Но есть НЕДОСТАТОК - невозможно работать с отрицательными числами и 0

3. использовать тангенсы:

любое число можно представить как тангенс угла `a = tan(x)`, поэтому можно воспользоваться тригонометрическим тождеством:

```
tan(x + y) = (tan(x) + tan(y)) / (1 - tan(x)*tan(y))
```

таким образом можно получить

```
1 - (a + b) / (tan(atan(a) + atan(b)) = a * b
```

т.е.

```
res = 1 - (a + b) / (Math.tan(Math.atan(a) + Math.atan(b))
```

НЕДОСТАТОЕ: вариант, когда `tan(atan(a) + atan(b) = 0` ну и опять из-за того, что функции высчитываются через ряды плывет точность (чтуь-чуть)

Comment: Только первый вариант `console.log( res = a / (1 / b) );`  вывел правильно `
0.02` остальные 
0.02 с хвостиком выводят 0.020000000000000004

Comment: ну это проблема сложных функций :) - ошибки при вычислении рядов, погрешности

Comment: я знаю)) вот пытаюсь найти универсальное решение, везде пишут что это и про что это, а как конкретно решить это никто не знает

Comment: универсальное решение для произведения без умножения?

Comment: можно с умножением, самое главное чтобы точность вычисления была на 100%, float со всеми знаками * / + -

Comment: @Serge88, `вывел правильно 0.02` Почему вы думаете, что это правильный ответ? Просто выведите чуть больше знаков: `(0.1*0.2).toFixed(20)`. А вообще, см.: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453).

Comment: добавил 3 способ для особых извращенцев :) по поводу точности - почитайте как устроены числа float - из-за того, что `log(2) / log(10)` - это иррациональное число, то чаще всего вы не сможете на компьютере получать действительные числа, соответствующие их десятичной записи

Answer (score 1):

```
exp(ln(a) + ln(b))
```

---

*Тело сообщения должно содержать не менее 30 символов; вы ввели 19.*

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так, у меня выводит ошибку `"ReferenceError: exp is not defined"`

Comment: @Serge88 https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+exp&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS847CA847&oq=javascript+exp&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l9.5004j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: `console.log( Math.exp(ln(a) + ln(b)) );` так тоже почему то выдает ошибку `ReferenceError: ln is not defined`

Comment: @Serge88 https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+ln&rlz=1C1OKWM_enCA854CA854&oq=javascript+ln&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512j0i22i30j0i10i22i30l2j0i22i30j0i10i22i30l4.4589j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 - замечаете тенденцию?

Comment: Написал так `console.log( Math.exp(Math.log(a) + Math.log(b)) );` но выводит почему то `0.02000000000000001` а должен `0.02`

Comment: toFixed не подойдет, так как неизвестно насколько обрезать

Comment: @Serge88 `.toFixed(15)`