# Как исправить неточности конвертации строки в число в R?

Tags: строки, r, конвертация, преобразование-типов, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

```
options(scipen=999)
options(digits=20)
> v5=w$V5

> v5
```

[1] "0.00545364023412378000000000" "0.00000000000000000000000000" "0.01179655021791500000000000" "0.00000000000000000000000000"
[5] "0.01913037521495690000000000" "0.01201045138062880000000000" "0.01249622079025910000000000" "0.01802093809125330000000000"
[9] "0.01046188940534250000000000" "0.03383881214608770000000000" "0.00000000000000000000000000" "0.00000000000000000000000000"
[13] "0.03722378016567200000000000" "0.00920251419434170000000000" "0.00895343534382711000000000" "0.00126196989698644000000000"
[17] "0.00000000000000000000000000" "0.03334279521442770000000000" "0.01039795649417310000000000" "0.00479748460279036000000000"
[21] "0.02666058417619530000000000" "0.02777456834015240000000000" "0.00626507213610722000000000" "0.01369786137780010000000000"
[25] "0.01431131263874400000000000" "0.00061611934303274800000000" "0.11063108557783600000000000" "0.00730418497066998000000000"
[29] "0.04216086961085650000000000" "0.00661873831127294000000000" "0.02321049545406370000000000" "0.02860393689448050000000000"
[33] "0.00814081242847531000000000" "0.00767969696667178000000000" "0.00688016609413842000000000" "0.03461042731932380000000000"
[37] "0.00984177026116521000000000" "0.00542580255441224000000000" "0.00000000000000000000000000" "0.00000000000000000000000000"
[41] "0.00953856033127113000000000" "0.00000000000000000000000000" "0.00000000000000000000000000" "0.00000000000000000000000000"
[45] "0.00000000000000000000000000" "0.00457922671443757000000000" "0.00982301412139612000000000" "0.00511194505909686000000000"
[49] "0.00463850952339640000000000" "0.00000000000000000000000000" "0.00000000000000000000000000" "0.01583219578947910000000000"
[53] "0.00129826373015778000000000" "0.01739128748816600000000000" "0.00502428007611189000000000" "0.00763982223820009000000000"
[57] "0.03879912932890770000000000" "0.00867717079752326000000000" "0.00768562925540900000000000" "0.05476620552621660000000000"
[61] "0.00944161555325990000000000" "0.00289253876401102000000000" "0.02207354502600600000000000" "0.01005909365009900000000000"
[65] "0.00000000000000000000000000" "0.01081131800530010000000000" "0.01063807027455490000000000" "0.01200500219657770000000000"
[69] "0.01944868652006510000000000" "0.01376399551567150000000000" "0.01061384054622340000000000" "0.00000000000000000000000000"
[73] "0.01545221754799480000000000" "0.05327523717996260000000000" "0.00000000000000000000000000" "0.00281537962416864000000000"
[77] "0.00708190176815232000000000"

```
> v6=as.numeric(v5)
> v6
```

[1] 0.00545364023412378031 0.00000000000000000000 0.01179655021791499968 0.00000000000000000000 0.01913037521495690105 0.01201045138062879943
[7] 0.01249622079025910007 0.01802093809125330029 0.01046188940534249941 0.03383881214608770033 0.00000000000000000000 0.00000000000000000000
[13] 0.03722378016567200187 0.00920251419434169916 0.00895343534382711005 0.00126196989698643992 0.00000000000000000000 0.03334279521442769928
[19] 0.01039795649417309988 0.00479748460279035959 0.02666058417619529899 0.02777456834015239878 0.00626507213610722011 0.01369786137780010064
[25] 0.01431131263874400004 0.00061611934303274797 0.11063108557783600527 0.00730418497066998018 0.04216086961085650092 0.00661873831127293959
[31] 0.02321049545406370096 0.02860393689448050003 0.00814081242847530979 0.00767969696667177969 0.00688016609413842021 0.03461042731932380268
[37] 0.00984177026116521067 0.00542580255441223961 0.00000000000000000000 0.00000000000000000000 0.00953856033127113007 0.00000000000000000000
[43] 0.00000000000000000000 0.00000000000000000000 0.00000000000000000000 0.00457922671443757034 0.00982301412139612029 0.00511194505909685990
[49] 0.00463850952339639987 0.00000000000000000000 0.00000000000000000000 0.01583219578947910045 0.00129826373015777996 0.01739128748816599901
[55] 0.00502428007611189012 0.00763982223820008997 0.03879912932890770133 0.00867717079752326065 0.00768562925540899975 0.05476620552621660337
[61] 0.00944161555325990012 0.00289253876401101987 0.02207354502600599941 0.01005909365009900053 0.00000000000000000000 0.01081131800530009922
[67] 0.01063807027455490085 0.01200500219657769929 0.01944868652006509838 0.01376399551567149965 0.01061384054622339923 0.00000000000000000000
[73] 0.01545221754799479957 0.05327523717996260344 0.00000000000000000000 0.00281537962416864018 0.00708190176815232022

```
> z=v5[1]
> z
```

[1] "0.00545364023412378000000000"

```
> y=as.numeric(z)
> y
```

[1] 0.0054536402341237803

```
> i=v5[3]
> i
```

[1] "0.01179655021791500000000000"

```
> j=as.numeric(i)
> j
```

[1] 0.011796550217915

> 

После конвертации хочу получить y=0.00545364023412378, а не 0.0054536402341237803

Неточная конвертация вызывает ошибки в дальнейших вычислениях. Есть способ получить из строки то число, которое в строке содержится, без потерь?

Нули после 16-го знака после запятой удалять пробовал, всё то-же самое.

```
> version
           _
```

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          4
minor          1.0
year           2021
month          05
day            18
svn rev        80317
language       R
version.string R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
nickname       Camp Pontanezen

Comment: вообще проблема [универсальна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/178576). но есть, конечно, и [r-специфичные](https://community.rstudio.com/t/a-question-on-floating-point-precision-in-r/37600) предложения (см. прикреплённую там [ссылку на pdf](https://stat.ethz.ch/Teaching/maechler/R/useR_2018/Maechler_Accuracy.pdf)).

Comment: Проблема совершенно точно специфична для R. Массив v5 это веса наблюдений. При тех-же самых вычислениях, проделанных в SPSS и даже в Эксель результаты получаются полностью корректными.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, не совсем правильно считать ехель образцом правильных вычислений и по нему валидировать другой софт. На этом простом примере видно, что ни о какой паранормальной точности (превышающей машинную, ограниченную двоичным представляем десятичных числе с заданной разрядностью) речь, мягко говоря, не идет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]