# Три числа, сумма обратных величин которых равна половине

Tags: python-3.x, математика, числа, арифметика

Найти три различных натуральных числа, не больших 16, сумма обратных величин которых равна 0,5.

Программа на Python-3 выдала только один ответ (с точностью до перестановки): (3, 10, 15):

```
for i in range (1, 17):
    for j in range (i+1, 17):
        for k in range (j+1, 17):
            if(1/i+1/j+1/k==1/2):
                print(i, j, k)
```

Но ведь есть ещё одно решение, (4, 6, 12). Почему программа его «‎не замечает»?

UPD: Зато [Еальферина](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%201%2Fx%2B1%2Fy%2B1%2Fz%3D1%2F2%20and%200%3Cx%3Cy%3Cz%3C17%20over%20the%20integers), наоборот, «‎видит» второе решение и не видит первого.

Comment: Преобразуйте `1/i+1/j+1/k==1/2` в `2 * (j * k + i * k + i * j) == i * j * k`. Вычисления с равенствами желательно делать в целых или рациональных числах. Сравнивать вещественные числа можно только если вы можете **доказать** достаточную точность вычислений.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что вычисления на числах с плавающей запятой [не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/282277) и сумма во втором случае равна
0.49999999999999994, а не 0.5.