# Как вычесть единицу из последней цифры его дробной части?

Tags: javascript

```js
var num = 21.58746;     // 21.58745
var num = 421;          // 420
var num = 0.8527777857; // 0.8527777856
```

Comment: Какую единицу????

Comment: @Air в комментарии число которое должно быть

Comment: В такой постановке никак. `0.100000 === 0.1` — как понять какую единицу нужно вычесть?

Comment: Ну и вообще изучите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/190728 в частности точность чисел с плавающей точкой

Comment: Наверное неправильно привел пример, убрал его `0.100000 === 0.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так, но возможны неточности из-за указанных в комментариях проблем с плавающей точкой

```js
var num1 = 21.58746;     // 21.58745
var num2 = 421;          // 420
var num3 = 0.8527777857; // 0.8527777856

function decOne(num) {
  // переводим в строку, вырезаем дробь, определяем длинну
  const frac_len = ((num + '').split('.')[1] || '').length
  return num - 1 / 10**frac_len
}

console.log(decOne(num1))
console.log(decOne(num2))
console.log(decOne(num3))
```

Answer (score 1):

касательно дробной части:

числа хранятся в двоичном виде, отображение для пользователей осуществляется в десятичном виде, поскольку `log(2)/log(10)` - иррациональное число, то однозначное соответствие десятичной и двоичной записей (однозначная точность) возникает только в случае, если число (дробная часть числа) представимо как степень двойки

таким образом однозначно ваша задача решаема только в очень редких случаях

однако вы можете попытаться грубой силой проделать данную операцию

1. перевести число в строку
2. разбить строку на 2 части (до точки и после точки)
3. перевести разбитые части в числа
4. вычесть из числа, соответствующего дробной части 1
5. если получилось отрицательное число, то создать строку, содержащую `9` по кол-ву равному длине строки, содержащей дробную часть, а из числа, соответствующего целой части вычесть 1
6. перевести оба числа в строки
   6.1) при этом дополнить строку отвечающую дробной части `0` в начале, так чтобы длина строки соответствовала длине разбитой строки
7. соединить строки через `.`
8. перевести строку в число :)

вот только не удивляйтесь если после того как у числа `3.1415926` вы вычели единицу и получили (в виде строки) `3.1415925`, после перевода в число вы все равно получили `3.1415926`

P.S.

конечно можно сделать более грубое, но при этом более точное выполнение вашей задачи

1. перевести число в строку
2. разбить на целую и дробную части
3. узнать длину дробной части
4. получить число `value = pow(10, -(len - 1))`
5. вычесть из первоначального числа полученное

только опять же не удивляйтесь, если вместо `3.1415925` вы получите `3.1415925999998`

P.P.S.

число пи просто привел для примера - на нем такого эффекта может и не быть