# разделение числа с плавающей точкой

Tags: c++

Я подаю число в консоле `1.2`
Как результат я должен получить

```
1        2
```

Если я подам число `124.55874`
То я получаю

```
124        55874
```

То есть моя задача выписывать целую часть цифр и часть с цифр после точки. И мой код работает, но если я подаю например число `12.12`, то получаю:

```
12        1.2+e07
```

Из за чего такие результаты? Из-за неточного бинарного представления некоторых чисел?

```
    double num, cN;
    std::cout << "num = ";
    std::cin >> num;
    while (num != 0.0) {
        std::cout << long (num) << "\t";
        cN = long (num);
        num = num - cN;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            num = num * 100;
        }
        while (long (num) % 10 == 0) {
            num = num / 10;
        }
        std::cout << num << "\n";
        std::cout << "num = ";
        std::cin >> num;
    }
```

Comment: `Из-за неточного бинарного представления некоторых чисел?` Да. ([Пример](https://rextester.com/SZQZT17710), [вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453)). Это тот случай, когда лучше воздержаться от использования арифметики с плавающей точкой. Например, просто считайте целое число, затем символ точки, и наконец ещё одно целое число.

Comment: Не совсем понял ваше решение проблемы. Просто считайте целое число - это я просто возьму `int (number)`, а дальше не понял

Comment: `int x, y; cin >> x; cin.get(); cin >> y;`

Comment: Моя вина, не обьяснил суть проблемы. В этом и она состоит, что пользователь подает именно даные типа float, и уже с этим числом нужно работать.

Comment: Дробная часть числа `12.12` равна `1199999999999992184029906638897955417633056640625`. Вас устроит такой ответ?

Comment: И таких чисел неограниченное колличество, да?

Comment: `И таких чисел неограниченное колличество, да?` Не совсем понял вопрос. Вы имеете ввиду количество цифр после запятой? Их конечное число.

Comment: Да читайте как строки до и после точки...

Comment: пользователь в консоль вводит символы, т.е. в любом случае весь пользовательский ввод - это строка символов. А потом перегруженные операторы >> или функции уже строки преобразуют в нужный формат, например в числа с плавающей точкой. Поэтому как написал Harry просто рассматривайте ввод как строка до точки, потом строка состоящая только из точки ".", потом строка после точки