# В чем ошибка trunc c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    double P,X,Y,All;
    cin >> P >> X >> Y;
    All=X+Y/100;
    P=P/100+1;
    All*=P;
    
    
    cout << trunc(All) << " " << trunc((All-trunc(All))*100);
    // cout << (All-trunc(All))*100; <- это равно 27
    
  return 0;
}
```

Входные данные: 13 179 0

Мой же вопрос состоит в том, что я немного не пойму одного: результат `(All-trunc(All))*100` равен 27 ( я это проверял), но почему trunc от этого числа равен 26?

Comment: @andreymal Входные данные: 13 179 0

Comment: `результат (All-trunc(All))*100 равен 27` [Я бы не был в этом так уверен](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47e3e4b835f88386).

Comment: Если отключить округление при выводе, то выяснится, что результат на самом деле равен 26.999999999998181 и trunc вполне логично выводит для него 26

Comment: @andreymal
Но тогда другой вопрос: почему там число 26.999999999998181? Когда по всем мат. правилам там 27. И как мне исправить мой код, чтобы было 27?

Comment: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой работают неправильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453)