# Наличие скобок в формуле округляют результат вычисления

Tags: python

Всем привет! Решал одну задачку и появился вот какой вопрос:
Почему в питоне

`(18 * 0.065325 - 20) * 6 / 1000 * 12 * 60 == -81.32032799999999`,

а если поставить скобки, то

`(18 * 0.065325 - 20) * (6 / 1000) * 12 * 60 == -81.320328`?

Прочитал про проблему 0.1 + 0.2 ([здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE)), но не особо понял, как все прочитанное укладывается на мою проблему.

Comment: про порядок действий в математике не забыли?

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev скобки тут не влияют на результат, тут именно из за плавающей точки

Comment: А для вас потеря единички в 14-м знаке после запятой реально проблема? Что за задачу вы решаете? Если это про деньги, то используйте `decimal`, а в остальных случаях это вообще не важно и да, `float` не идеально точный и это всё объясняет.

Comment: @CrazyElf тест не прошел, отсюда и возник такой вопрос. Для меня это не особо и проблема

Comment: @hjbaa Ну, это какой-то неправильный тест, который `float` на точное равенство проверяет, а не сравнивает модуль разницы с эпсилоном

Comment: @CrazyElf не спорю, но разобраться захотелось, в чем проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я уже написал в комментарии, учитывайте порядок операций. Сначала выполняются операции в скобках

> (18 * 0.065325 - 20)*6/1000 = -0.11294489999999999

> (18 * 0.065325 - 20)*(6/1000) = -0.1129449

в первом случае сначала значение из скобок умножается на 6, затем делится на 1000, во втором - значение из первых скобок умножается на значение из вторых скобок (0.006)

Далее можно читать по вашей ссылке, там как раз все прекрасно расписано

Comment: т.к. умножение на 6 с последующим делением на 1000 математически то же самое, что умножение на 0.006, то причина заключается как раз в машинном представлении дробных чисел, а не в порядке вычисления! С этими данными правильный результат получается со скобками, с другими данными правильный результат окажется без скобок. Вы объяснили симптомы, а не причину.