# Цикл for не совершает последнюю итерацию

Tags: c++, for

Столкнулся с проблемой в следующем коде:

```
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    double b, x;
    cout << "Введите значение b: ";
    cin >> b;
    double U;
    for (x = 2; x <= 4; x += 0.2)
    {
        
        if (x < 3)
            U = 2.75 * log(abs(b * x)) - sqrt(abs(log(x + b)));
        else if (x == 3.)
            U = x - 2. * sin(b / x);
        else
            U = exp(x) + log(x) - (10 * x);
        cout << "x = " << x << endl;
        cout << "U = " << U << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

Код работает, но цикл не совершает последнюю итерацию. При этом, если я делаю следующую конструкцию, код работает правильно:

```
for (x = 2; x <= 4;)
    {
     x += 0.2;
    }
```

Почему цикл for не совершает последнюю итерацию?

Comment: Итерироваться числами с точкой - ОЧЕНЬ плохая идея. Лучше переходите на int и внутри цикла его как надо делите (на 5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема тут в том, что `2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2` равно `4.000000000000002`, что больше 4. Из-за этого последняя итерация и пропускается.

Подробнее можно почитать тут: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой работают неправильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/178779)

Чтобы избежать такого эффекта, надо ослабить условие. Например, можно оставить уступку в половину шага:

```
for (x = 2; x < 4.1; x += 0.2)
```

Или же можно попробовать округлять x до десятых перед сравнением:

```
for (x = 2; round(x*10)/10 <= 4; x += 0.2)
```

Наконец, самый надёжный вариант - считать в целых числах:

```
for (int xn = 20; xn  <= 40; xn += 2) {
    double x = xn / 10.0;
}
```