# Почему расчет суммы элементов массива при последовательном и параллельном вычислении дает разный результат?

Tags: java, распараллеливание

Всем добрый день. Есть следующее задание: Требуется реализовать параллельный алгоритм получения суммы последовательности элементов вида 1/a[i] с использованием класса RecursiveAction.
Моя реализация была такая:
'''

```
package com.company;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
        double[] data = new double[100000];
        double result=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = (double) i+1;
            //System.out.println(data[i]);
        }

        SumArr app = new SumArr(data, 0, data.length);
        pool.invoke(app);

        System.out.println("Параллельное вычисление: " + app.result);

        for (int i = 0; i<data.length;i++ )
        {
            result += 1/data[i];
        }
        result = (result/data.length);
        System.out.println("Последовательное вычисление: " + result);
    }
}

class SumArr extends RecursiveAction{

    final int LIMIT = 100;
    double result;
    int start, end;
    double[] data;
    SumArr(double[] data, int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.data = data;
    }
    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if((end - start)< LIMIT){
            for(int i= start;i<end;i++){
                result+= 1/data[i];

            }
            result = (result/data.length);


        }else {
            int mid = (start + end)/2;
            SumArr left = new SumArr(data, start, mid);
            SumArr right = new SumArr(data, mid, end);
            left.fork();
            right.fork();
            left.join();
            right.join();
            result = left.result + right.result;

        }
    }
}
```

'''

Однако при выводе результатов оказывается, что числа после запятой отличаются в последних знаках. В чем может быть проблема и как можно исправить?
[image: Результат выполнения. Последние числа после запятой различаются при величине массива свыше 10000]

Comment: Потому что ошибки округления

Comment: Вместо `Double` лучше использовать `BigDecimal`

Comment: У вас совпадение до 12 десятичного знака, это практически равные числа

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой работают неправильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be)