# Почему при преобразовании int = 1234567890 в float, получается 1.23456794E9 а не 1234567890.0?

Tags: java, преобразование-типов

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
       int big = 1234567890;
     System.out.println(gerDifference(int big))
  }
    public static int getDifference (int big) {
       float approx = big; //approx: 1.23456794E9.  big:1234567890
       return big - (int)approx;
  }
}
```

Comment: Это одно и то же число, просто представленное в экспоненциальной форме. Вы можете управлять видом вывода с помощью функций форматирования

Comment: Код не компилируется, если что.

Comment: Да уж, в коде как минимум две грубых ошибки. Но в остальном причины две: 1) Для `float` стандартная нотация научная, это вопрос представления, 2) Типа `float` недостаточно для представления чисел с такой точностью

Comment: Не нужно минусовать вопрос. Не помню, чтобы в большинстве книг объяснялись такие тонкости.

Comment: Большое спасибо всем за ответы! предварительно пытался найти ответы на основных русскоязычных ресурсах по java, но там такие тонкости не прописаны - просто общее объяснение преобразования примитивов....

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Но тут же не только про экспоненциальную форму, но и про пропадание значащих цифр. Так то я бы тоже согласился с дубликатом, но.

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, возможно, классический вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/178576 тоже стоит привязать как дубликат.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Я проголосовал, но не помню можем ли мы два дубля привязать или это только модератор умеет. Посмотрим, как закроется дублем )

Comment: @CrazyElf, [тысячник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers) тоже может редактировать список дубликатов.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь есть два момента:

1. Целое число при преобразовании в вещественное одинарной точности теряет значащие цифры - потому что для хранения мантиссы (цифр) вещественного одинарной точности отводится меньше разрядов (24), чем у целого 32-битового.
2. Вещественное число выводится на экран в экспоненциальной форме - потому что так принято по-умолчанию для чисел, у которых 7 значащих цифр (для одинарной точности) не рядом с десятичной точкой (от Х,ХХХХХХ (тут точно не уверен) до ХХХХХХХ).