# Дробная часть числа Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Перепробовал уже кучу всего, но в любом случае вместо многих чисел, например 0,32 выводит 0,32000000000000006

Пробовал

```
math.modf(x)
whole = int(n // 1)
dec = x - int(x)
x%1
```

Comment: `0.32` в виде числа с плавающей точкой задать невозможно никак. [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой работают неправильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453)

Answer (score 1):

Там, где важно идеально точно работать с десятичными дробями (например, в финансовых вычислениях), никогда не используют числа с плавающей точкой - для этого есть специальный модуль `decimal`:

```
from decimal import Decimal

x = 1.32
d = Decimal('1.32')

print( x % 1 )  // число с плавающей точкой даёт неточный результат
print( d % 1 )  // число в формате Decimal даёт точный результат
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html