# C++ Boost cpp_dec_float_100 выдает разные ответы

Tags: c++, boost

```
cpp_dec_float_100 x = 0.00000000000001;  
cpp_dec_float_100 z = 0.00000000000008;  
cpp_dec_float_100 y = 0.1;  
cout << setprecision(100) << x +z + y; 
 
//0.100000000000090005551115123125676439960068731336843652116562475296035472638322971761226654052734375
```

```
cpp_dec_float_100 x = (cpp_dec_float_100)"0.00000000000001"; 
cpp_dec_float_100 z = (cpp_dec_float_100)"0.00000000000008"; 
cpp_dec_float_100 y = (cpp_dec_float_100)"0.1"; 
cout << setprecision(100) << x +z + y;

//0.10000000000009
```

Почему первый вариант записи кода дает неверный ответ?

Comment: Во втором случае функции класса `cpp_dec_float_100` посимвольно анализируют строковые литералы и формируют корректные значения. А в первом случае преобразованию подвергаются _литералы с плавающей точкой_ типа `double`. Т.к. вещественные числа `0.00000000000001` и `0.1` типом `double` формата IEEE 754 [не представимы точно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453) ([пример](https://godbolt.org/z/9jnK8GMcr)), то получаем неверный ответ.

Comment: @wololo, оформьте, пожалуйста, ответом.