# Не могу убрать лишний вывод C#

Tags: c#

Уже голову сломал, по несколько раз переписывал программу с нуля, менял условие и в итоге ничего не меняется. В программе идет итерация по промежутку от а до b с шагом табуляции и в консоль нужно вывести все значения которые принимает функция. Вот вывод программы:

```
a = -0,9; b = -0,4; h = 0,05
Input a = -0,9
Input b = -0,4
Input h = 0,05
x = -0,90        y = -0,62993
x = -0,85        y = -0,55074
x = -0,80        y = -0,47320
x = -0,75        y = -0,39922
x = -0,70        y = -1,77059
x = -0,65        y = -1,87475
x = -0,60        y = 2,65673
x = -0,55        y = 3,20433
x = -0,50        y = 3,91632
x = -0,45        y = 4,87059
x = -0,40        y = 4,87059
```

В конечном итоге нужно убрать из вывода последнюю итерацию в x = -0,4.

Вот код:

```
using System;
using static System.Math;
namespace Program
{
    class Programm
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a = -0,9; b = -0,4; h = 0,05");
            Lab2_a lab = new Lab2_a();
            lab.Input();
            lab.cycle();
            lab.Output();
        }
    }
    class Lab2_a : Znach
    {
        public void Input()
        {
            Console.Write("Input a = ");
            a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Input b = ");
            b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Input h = ");
            h = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        }
        public override void Output()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("x = {0:F2}\t y = {1:F5}", x, y);
        }
    }
    abstract class Znach
    {
        public double a, b, x, y, h;
        public void cycle()
        {
            for(x = a; x <= b; x += h)
            {
                if (x <= -0.7)
                {
                    y = Atan(Pow(x, 3));
                }
                else if (x > -0.7 && x <= -0.6)
                {
                    y = Tan(x + Math.Log(Math.Abs(x)));
                }
                else 
                {
                    y = 1 /Tan(Pow(x, 2));
                }
                Output();
            }
        }
        public abstract void Output();
    }
}
```

Comment: Хотя вопрос не совсем понятен, но может быть `for(x = a; x < b; x += h)`? То есть `x` строго меньше `b`.

Comment: этот вариант в первую очередь пробовал, но вывод тот же

Comment: Это же вещественные числа с плавающей точностью. Я бы ставил условие типа `x < (b-h/2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если изменить

```
Console.WriteLine("x = {0:F2}\t y = {1:F5}", x, y);
```

на

```
Console.WriteLine("x = {0:R}\t y = {1:R}", x, y);
```

то можно заметить, что `x = -0,40` на самом деле `x = -0.39999999999999974`.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417454/299581

---

Все, что я написал выше, конечно, интересно, но...

```
lab.Input();
lab.cycle();
lab.Output();
```

В `lab.cycle` уже есть `Output()`, дополнительно вызывать его после `lab.cycle()` не нужно.

Если в приведенном вами коде убрать дополнительный `lab.Output()`, то `x = -0,4` "уберется".
Также нужно использовать строгое неравенство.

А если вы хотите, чтобы `x` был включительно до `b`, то можно использовать информацию из ссылки выше и делать сравнение с допуском: `(x - b) < 0.001`.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в точности вычислений. Чтобы работало лучше, стоит посчитать число шагов заранее и использовать умножение, а не сложение: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##rY2xCsIwGIT3/ymOTolNawYdNGZydXdOa6Q/lATaKoXSZ48RRxcHt4/j7r52rNqRU7rFR9N7OFhUuj4oNB/aKXSZdK33hugeBwgOE9hqhWDfLIVoKie3nTTgUzAoS5a0EPB0A@Y8dijB2KAzOTzHMMbe19eBJ3/h4EWx6GP@12uhMEtDK9F3Sf5kt//Qp/QC)

```
double a = -0.9, b = -0.4, h = 0.05;

for (int i=0, n=(int)((b-a)/h); i<n; ++i)
{
  var x = a + i * h;
  Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", x);
}

Console.WriteLine();

for (int i=0, n=(int)((b-a)/h); i<=n; ++i)
{
  var x = a + i * h;
  Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", x);
}
```

Я не стал использовать округление из-за того, что у тебя данные вводятся пользователем и нет гарантии, что разность делится нацело. Возможно, тут всё равно стоит какой-то эпсилон добавить, чтобы компенсировать возможные погрешности, но я не уверен. Если бы было гарантированно известно, что должно быть деление нацело, я бы округлил математически.