# Что использовать для простых и правильных вычислений десятичных дробей?

Tags: python, float, поиск-библиотек

Какой модуль, какие функции и.т.п. использовать, чтобы сделать `1.5-1.3` и получить `0.2`? Ах да, потом еще и сохранить `0.2` так, чтобы потом оно не стало каким-нибудь `0.1999999998`?
(Получить от пользователя ввод числа 1, числа 2 и сделать их вычисления?)

Почитал интернет, я правильно понял, что мне нужно **переводить хранение всех чисел в строки**, и дальше как то так?:

```
from decimal import Decimal as D

a = str(1.5)
b = str(1.3)
print(D(a) - D(b)) # выводит 0.2, ура!
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html

Comment: Добавьте метку [поиск-библиотек]

Comment: А чем не подходит модуль decimal, который вы у себя в коде успешно применяете?

Comment: @MBo А `0.2` то как получить?

Comment: "Почитал интернет, я правильно понял, что мне нужно переводить хранение всех чисел в строки, и дальше как то так?:" - не в строки, а в объекты Decimal, ну и лучше сразу строковыми литералами инициализировать `a = "1.5"`, `b = "1.3"`, чтобы нигде периодическая двоичная дробь не закралась.

Comment: @insolor Да, в общем то, все не так плохо... И я уже как бы смирился, что сейчас пойду искать все места, где может быть дробь, и перегонять это в строки... Но вообще неприятно, да... Такая... подлянка от питона...

Comment: @insolor а в mysql этот decimal запихать можно? Если нет, значит в строки...

Comment: Это не подлянка от питона, это в принципе особенность чисел с плавающей точкой, см.: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417454/1365. В MySQL вроде бы есть decimal тип.

Comment: А вообще, если у вас не предполагается точность результата больше одной цифры после запятой, можно просто округлять результаты операций до одного знака. И можно это делать только при выводе, что вообще правильным форматированием вывода решается. Для многих практических задач такого подхода будет вполне достаточно (но не для денежных задач).

Comment: @insolor спасибо, буду думать.