# Почему при делении float на четное число и сложении получается не точное число?

Tags: python, float

Исходные данные (float):
level = -17.0,
h = 0.84

Результат:
level/100 + h = 0.6699999999999999

Вопрос: как без округлений получить очевидное 0,67? Я же не на нечетное делю. В чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в устройстве компьютера, он так работает. А зачем вам нужно получить именно 0,67? Чем не устраивает полученный результат?

Comment: Вещественное число `0.67` в формате [binary64 IEEE 754](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) не представимо. Два ближайших вещественных числа, которые можно представить точно в данном формате — это `0.67000000000000003996802888650563545525074005126953125` и `0.6699999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875`. См. [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой работают неправильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы работать без округлений, переходите к целым числам. Если вам нужна точность представления два знака после запятой, то умножьте все ваши числа на 100 и преобразуйте в целые. Проводите нужные операции и храните в памяти целые числа. При выводе куда-то (для человека, в файл для обмена) делите на 100.