# Python неправильно считает. Как это исправить?

Tags: python, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Я пишу

```
print(0.1 + 0.2 + 0.3)
```

Вывод:

```
0.6000000000000001
```

Как это исправить?
Я пробовал написать

```
from decimal import *
print(Decimal(0.1) + Decimal(0.2) + Decimal(0.3))
```

и получил вывод

```
0.6000000000000000055511151231
```

Мне не нужна какая-то конкретная точность (то есть, `getcontext().prec = number` не подойдёт), а нужно убирать нули в конце числа после точки до тех пор, пока их не останется. Ну или подойдёт, если каким-то образом определить number.

Comment: Это не погрешность, так у всех. Обновите питон, по-моему, это убрали после 3.1.

Comment: У меня Python 3.8 или даже позже.

Comment: Изучите тогда [вот эту](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/operatsii-chislami-python/problemy-chisel-plavajuschej-zapjatoj/) статью по вашей проблеме.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, лучший способ с этим бороться — применять `format` либо `f`-строки.

Comment: Используйте `round` для округления

Comment: Про `format` и `f`-строки я знаю. Но точность - не константа, т.к. погрешность может быть разная. Надо эту точность как-то определить.

Comment: Нужно перейти на квантовый компьютер, а это старье всё так считает.;)

Comment: @Сергей Кох Если дашь деньги на него, перейду :)

Comment: `Decimal` нужно конструировать из строк: `Decimal('0.1') + Decimal('0.2') + Decimal('0.3')`. [Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

Comment: Помогло! Жаль, что я не могу отметить комментарий лучшим! :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой работают неправильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from decimal import *
print(Decimal("0.1") + Decimal("0.2") + Decimal("0.3"))
```