# Как производить корректное умножение/деление чисел в формате float?

Tags: python, float

Как избавиться от такого?

```
i = 305.9
n = i * 100
print(n)
30589.999999999996
```

Есть более глобальный способ, или нужно округлять `round`'ом после каждого действия?

Comment: Можете попробовать decimal https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: То есть, вместо "округлять round'ом после каждого действия" придется прописывать Decimal перед каждым числом?

Comment: Грубо говоря да

Comment: @agassi не перед каждым числом, только там где у вас число с плавающей точкой. В вашем примере достаточно будет только i прописать как `i = Decimal("305.9")`. Округлять тоже нужно после каждого действия, а только там где у вас идет вывод.

Comment: Либо печатать только нужное вам число знаков после запятой `print(f'{n:.2f}')`

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой работают неправильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/1365), [Почему нельзя получить точное число?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/291468/1365)

Answer (score 1):

1. Округлять при выводе до приемлемого количества знаков после запятой:

   ```
   i = 305.9
   n = i * 100
   print(f"{n:.2f}")  # 30590.00
   ```

   Округлять постоянно при каждом действии не нужно.
2. Использовать класс `Decimal`

   ```
   from decimal import Decimal

   i = Decimal("305.9")
   n = i * 100
   print(n)  # 30590.0
   ```

   Опять же, не нужно все оборачивать в `Decimal` - а только там, где у вас появляется дробное число. Например, при вводе числа пользователем.

   Но стоит учитывать, что `Decimal` работает медленнее, чем `float`. Модуль [`decimal`](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Modules/_decimal) сейчас написан на Си, так что разница в производительности для CPython будет не в сотни раз, а максимум раз в 10 (рандомный бенчмарк на моем компютере на CPython 3.8 показал разницу ~в два раза), но если производительность критична, лучше `Decimal` не использовать.